# Regarding GWT in Admin of BroadLeaf Commerce

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, view, broadleaf-commerce

Hope all are doing good.

```
I am using BroadLeaf Commerce. 
As we know that , BroadLeafCommerece uses GWT in Admin Module. How can I create a GWT form after clicking a button.
I am unable to find the Controller which is going to generate the Form Component. Please solve this problem ASAP.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Broadleaf are you using? The GWT admin was completely removed in version 3.0+ and we recommend that version to everyone using Broadleaf for new projects along with migrating 2.x implementations to 3.0. We have provided some migration docs on docs.broadleafcommerce.org.

Comment: Thanks for Reply. We are using BLC3.03. Can u say , How to customize Admin Part? I mean , We have a requirement to put a button in the Admin Page. How can we do that ? @phillipuniverse